# Merging MVC4 membership database with entity framework code first database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using MVC4 with the default membership provider and using entity framework code first. The membership data is in a database stored in my app_data folder called aspnet-xxxxxx.mdf, and my application data is created in a separate database running on SQL Server express.

What do I have to do so that I have 1 database containing my membership tables and the application data? I do not mind losing the data in either of these databases as at the moment it is only test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find your InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs and change in the line

```cs
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("[ConnectionString]", builder.Provider, "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);
```

`[ConnectionString]` to your connection string name you defined in Web.config. Or provide a complete connection string

Comment: I have done this and I can see what it is trying to do, but the database I specified in the connectionstring does not have the membership provider tables, and autoCreateTables is set to false. Is there a way to automatically add these tables to my database? (setting autoCreateTables to true throws an error)